# Which polite formula to say "Likewise"

Tags: word-choice, politeness

Sometimes on forums I see such messages as: "If you have any questions please, free to contact me!" or "If you need my help, you can ask me anytime". In such situations I want to be polite too and say not just "thank you", but something like "the same to you", "mutually", "likewise", "I wish the same to you". But I don't know which word to choose. Please tell me which word do you write in response to such messages? And what is more natural to say. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you "will": I think it can't be said (?)

Comment: You can use **"You too"** as a simple reply.

Answer (score 2):

Long form: Thanks.  Feel free to contact me as well if you have any questions.

Short form: Thanks.  Same to you.  (assuming the forum is an informal environment)

However, on many forums, you might want avoid such chit-chat since it's implied in the forum environment.